# Key mapping across different Tabs

Tags: key-bindings, gvim

I have mapped F10 key to execute different programs (pdflatex, python) depending on the
file extension.

```
autocmd Filetype tex map <F10> :lcd %:p:h<CR> :bel ter pdflatex % <CR>
autocmd Filetype python map <F10> :lcd %:p:h<CR> :bel ter python3 % <CR>
```

If I open a tex file and then press F10, pdflatex is executed.
If I then open a python file in a new tab and press F10, python is executed.
But now if I now switch back to the tab having the tex file and press F10, python
is executed and not pdflatex. Vim is mapping F10 as per the extension of the
last opened file and not the extension of the current file. Can someone please
help me resolve the issue.
Thank you

Comment: As the answer points out, your issue is related to switching buffers, not tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use buffer-local mappings (see `:h :map-local`):

```
autocmd Filetype tex map <buffer> <F10> :lcd %:p:h<CR> :bel ter pdflatex % <CR>
autocmd Filetype python map <buffer> <F10> :lcd %:p:h<CR> :bel ter python3 % <CR>
```

But these ^ mappings in auto-commands have some unrelated problems:

- You should wrap autocmd in an autocmd group (see `:h augroup`)<sup>1</sup>
- You should use `noremap` instead of `map` to avoid recursive mapping<sup>2</sup>
- You should map this only in normal mode (see `:nn`)<sup>3</sup>

So a better set of autocommands would be this:

```
augroup FTMaps
  au!
  autocmd Filetype tex nnoremap <buffer> <F10> :lcd %:p:h<CR> :bel ter pdflatex % <CR>
  autocmd Filetype python nnoremap <buffer> <F10> :lcd %:p:h<CR> :bel ter python3 % <CR>
augroup END
```

---

1. `augroup` helps you redefining auto-commands easily when you source your `$MYVIMRC` again.
2. Otherwise, mapping `j` to `jk`, for example, will get vim stuck in forever converting `j` to `jk` because `j` exists in the right-hand-side of the map command.
3. Because the right-hand-side is usable only in normal mode.

Comment: I would prefer `nnoremap` instead of `noremap` here as mapping body only make sense for normal mode.

Comment: @MaximKim, done.